# javascript function calling in loop

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm making a map using leaflet.js.

I made a function where user selects a country and it generates easybuttons with that selection with specific information.

The problem is when I select one country after another it creates more easybuttons and doesn't remove the previously created button.

[image]

Please check the image so you can know what the problem is.

```
function generateList() {
    const list = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
    
    countryList.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (a.properties.country < b.properties.country) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.properties.country > b.properties.country) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    
    countryList.forEach((country) => {
      
      
      const a=document.createElement('a');
      const p=document.createElement('p');
      
      
      //flying to the country on user click on country
      a.addEventListener('click', () => {
        
          flyToStore(country);
          const city=country.properties.city;
          const currency1=country.properties.currency;
          const contry=country.properties.country;
          
          L.easyButton('fa-solid fa-cloud fa-lg',function (){
           weatherdetails(city);
           $('#weathermodal').modal('show');
        
        }).addTo(myMap);
        L.easyButton('fa fa-dollar fa-lg',function (){
            currencyexchange(currency1);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
         
         }).addTo(myMap);
         L.easyButton('fa fa-info-circle fa-lg',function (){
            moredetails(contry);
            $('#detailsmodal').modal('show');
         
         }).addTo(myMap);
         
      });
      
      
      a.classList.add('country-item');
      
      countries=country.properties.country;
      a.innerText =countries ;
     
      
      
      
  
      //div.appendChild(p);
      
    list.appendChild(p);
    p.appendChild(a);
      
    });
```

}

Comment: You will have to actually remove the old button, it will not magically happen for you..

Comment: That's what I'm asking that how can I remove the old button every time I Click on new country?

Comment: Here is a possible solution
[Leaflet remove easybutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561876/leaflet-remove-easybutton-control-from-leaflet-map) map.removeControl(backButton);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to hold a reference to that button instance. Then call your map `removeControl` it.

```
function generateList() {
    const list = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');

    countryList.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.properties.country < b.properties.country) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a.properties.country > b.properties.country) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    lastButton1 = null;
    lastButton2 = null;
    lastButton3 = null;

    countryList.forEach((country) => {

        const a = document.createElement('a');
        const p = document.createElement('p');

        //flying to the country on user click on country
        a.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (lastButton1) {
                myMap.removeControl(lastButton1);
                myMap.removeControl(lastButton2);
                myMap.removeControl(lastButton3);
                lastButton1 = null
            }

            flyToStore(country);
            const city = country.properties.city;
            const currency1 = country.properties.currency;
            const contry = country.properties.country;

            lastButton1 = L.easyButton('fa-solid fa-cloud fa-lg', function () {
                weatherdetails(city);
                $('#weathermodal').modal('show');
            })
            lastButton2 = L.easyButton('fa fa-dollar fa-lg', function () {
                currencyexchange(currency1);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            })
            lastButton3 = L.easyButton('fa fa-info-circle fa-lg', function () {
                moredetails(contry);
                $('#detailsmodal').modal('show');
            })

            lastButton1.addTo(myMap);
            lastButton2.addTo(myMap);
            lastButton3.addTo(myMap);

        });

        a.classList.add('country-item');

        countries = country.properties.country;
        a.innerText = countries;

        //div.appendChild(p);

        list.appendChild(p);
        p.appendChild(a);

    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks that works but we just need to place that if condition inside the eventlistener